# Need help outputting text nodes from XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I don't know anything about XSLT but I need it for a one time thing. This should be pretty simple to do. What would the XSLT need to be to take the following input and display as what is shown below.

INPUT:

```
<TestResult>
<set-value idref="account_lockout_duration_var">900</set-value>
<set-value idref="account_lockout_threshold_var">5</set-value>
    <group>
      <id>345</id>
      <id>265</id>
      <field>true</field>
      <message>dont do that</message>
    </group>
    <group>
      <id>333</id>
      <field>false</field>
    </group>
</TestResult>
```

OUTPUT

```
345,265,true
333,false
```

This is just a snippet, there can only be one field element per group but id elements are unbound.

I modified the input, using the below answers, I get extra output (everything is output, when I only want the id and field elements.
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like this:

**XML:**

```
<TestResult>
  <set-value idref="account_lockout_duration_var">900</set-value>
  <set-value idref="account_lockout_threshold_var">5</set-value>
  <group>
    <id>345</id>
    <id>265</id>
    <field>true</field>
    <message>dont do that</message>
  </group>
  <group>
    <id>333</id>
    <field>false</field>
  </group>
</TestResult>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/TestResult/group">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::group">
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>  
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/TestResult/group/id|field">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="following-sibling::id or following-sibling::field">,</xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OUT:**

```
345,265,true
333,false
```

Comment: I think your rule `xsl:template match="node()|@*"` isn't really needed. See my answer for more compact code.

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="group">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="id">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="field">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="group/*[not(self::message)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(.,substring(',&#xA;',
                                                 1 + boolean(self::field),
                                                 1))"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
345,265,true
333,false
```